# Extending xhtml schema to support custom tags and attributes

Tags: xhtml, xsd, dtd, expando

I want to provide the xml schema for custom tags and attributes, which are extending xhtml, so that I would have auto suggest in the IDE (I am using WebStorm) for standard html tags and attributes and for my custom. The namespace should not be used, so that as in the example below the name of the element is `my-custom-element`, but not `my:custom-element`.

I have achieved this with DTD have this:

```xml
<!ENTITY % XHTML1-strict PUBLIC "-//W3C//XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"        
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" >
%XHTML1-strict;

<!ELEMENT my-custom-element ANY>
```

Is it possible to do the same using xsd?

**Update:**
The above example is not correct, as new custom element is auto completed only outside of html tag

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML5 DTD](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/tree/master/contrib/catalogs/html5) from Komodo, which is an extension of the XHTML DTD, as a guideline for adding new elements. There are several tools to convert DTD2XSD and XSD2DTD, such as:

- [dtd2xsd.xsl](http://people.apache.org/~andyc/neko/doc/dtd/conversions.html)
- [dtd2xsd.pl](http://www.w3.org/2000/04/schema_hack/)
- [xsd2dtd.xsl](http://crism.maden.org/consulting/pub/xsl/xsd2dtd.xsl)
- [Custom DTD](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/)